# Sending commands from spa to thermal commands

Tags: javascript, angular, printing, single-page-application, thermal-printer

I have a spa. I am trying to print to the the thermal printer (label and receipt). Unfortunately, I had no success

My thermal printer is Xprinter XP-235B, I have tried:

1. Building a local mini server (with .NET Core - using `PrintDocument`) to communicate with my spa however I feel this solution is does not work as intended (it need to be calibrated a lot). I have tried zpl commands in c# but it looks like all library are old and out dated. (or support only ip protocoal not usb)
2. Building electron app with electron-pos-printer however it looks like it is out dated and the developers have forgot about it.

I have reached a mental block. Any suggestions to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve your problem? I print to thermal printers with Electron.
You normally create a new window, then print the window.

You probably don't want to use the remote method, but you could convert this:

```
printElectron(contents: string, printerName: string, options: printOptions) : boolean {

    let printWindow = new this.electronService.remote.BrowserWindow({ width: 350, height: 600 })

    printWindow.loadURL(contents)
      .then( e => {

        if (options.silent) {
          printWindow.hide();
        }

        if (!options) {
          options = {
            silent: true,
            printBackground: false,
            deviceName: printerName
          }
        }

        printWindow.webContents.print(
          options,
          (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
              // console.log('data', data)
              if (error == true)  {
                printWindow.close();
                printWindow = null;
                return false
              }
            }
            if (data) {
              printWindow.close();
              printWindow = null;
              return true
            }
          }
        )

        }).catch( err => {
          console.log('error', err)
          printWindow.close();
          printWindow = null;
          return false
        }
    )
    return false;
  }
```